# GSUB with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I edit the memos below to remove QPC CANCEL and the following letters and numbers after the first set of numbers?

Input:

```
Memo field: QPC CANCEL 861518069 CONV. TO Test Receipt 1430
Memo field: QPC CANCEL 8615315362 Another test transaction
Memo field: QPC CANCEL 86151343 Our third test transaction
```

Output:

```
Memo field: 861518069
Memo field: 8615315362
Memo field: 86151343
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t(col) as(
values
('Memo field: QPC CANCEL 861518069 CONV. TO Test Receipt 1430'),
('Memo field: QPC CANCEL 8615315362 Another test transaction'),
('Memo field: QPC CANCEL 86151343 Our third test transaction')
)

select substring(col from 'QPC CANCEL\s*(\d+)' ) from t
```

Comment: what is field data type ?

Comment: Thank you and it's a text field!

Comment: May be there are not exactly one spaces between `QPC CANCEL` and numbers? add asterisk  after `\s` like this: `select substring(col from 'QPC CANCEL\s*(\d+)' ) from t` and see what happens

Comment: about `edit the transactions`, do you need actually update column ?